# How can we use variables in wxl file

Tags: localization, wix, windows-installer

I have a "wxi" file that has all my variables defined. I include this file in my "wxs" to incorporate the variables.

As per requirement I used the variables in my localization file "wxl". Tried using $(var.var_name). But that fails to render the variable's value.

Also tried to define property in my wxs file and use the same in "wxl" using [PROPERTY_NAME]. But I see that the installer renders '[PROPERTY_NAME]' as a text and not its value that is defined in my "wxs".

Is there any other way to use variable in "wxl" file?

Comment: See answer from @BobArnson http://stackoverflow.com/a/6833470/1035521