# WiX (Windows Installer Xml), Create universal variables

Tags: windows, wix

I was studying for WiX for several days through some online tutorial. I saw three cases to create some variables

1. `<? define Variable = "value" ?>` and then use the value as `$(var.Variable)`
2. Create a localization file. Type in content as `<String Id="Variable">Value</String>` and then use the value as `!(loc.Variable)`
3. Create a include file. Type in content as `<Property Id="VARIABLE" Value="value" />` and then include the file, use the property in Fragment as `[VARIABLE]`

I know the localization file is mainly used for different locales. But I don't know when we should use each case. Can anyone help explain?

Comment: You might still end up with three choices but Properties are a Windows Installer feature, not a WiX feature, and any of the three can be used in a WiX include file-that's an independent concept. In general, it seems like the tutorial is overusing the word variable and creating false equivalencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used these constructs that much. However, I think **Bob Arnson** (WiX developer) explains this pretty well in [**this blog entry about localization**](https://www.joyofsetup.com/2013/02/06/l10nm10n-localization-minimization/) (the explanation is good, but I still manage to confuse myself - carbon error).

***Essentially***:

- **[Preprocessor](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html) variables** - **`$(var.Variable)`** - are resolved by the WiX preprosessor - it happens before compilation (`Candle.exe`).
- **Localization variables** - **`!(loc.LanguageLcid)`** - are resolved at link time (`Light.exe`). The linking process can spit out multiple MSI files in different languages. Hence localization is a link-time process.
- See **link 3** below for a localization sample. Once you localize, you localize most or all fields. In the sample below I don't localize `version` and `upgrade code` - they remain the same for all output MSI files.
- You have to determine in each case what should be localized. Should the `Manufacturer` name be localized? Perhaps if you want Asian characters for Asian setups, and an equivalent Latin character name otherwise?
- **Include files** are simply included in the WiX source before compilation. It is like including a header file in C++. This makes it a preprocessor construct. See **link 2** below for a discussion of the use of include files.
- **UPDATE**: There are also [**Burn Engine Variables**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51460578/129130) - if you make `setup.exe` launchers with WiX.

  - https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/variable.html
- WixVariable:

  - https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/wixvariable.html
  - [WixVariable Sample](https://github.com/shannon-sys/mongodb/blob/4501fa4c52ba08a84b323126ef7138feba20f549/src/mongo/installer/msi/wxs/Installer_64.wxs#L12)

I am sure there are other technical reasons as well. [Rob](http://robmensching.com/blog/) or [Bob](https://www.joyofsetup.com/) would need to illuminate. There could also be differences in `WiX 4` than what I am used to in `WiX 3` - and there could be changes planned that I am unaware of.

---

***Some Links***:

1. [Is it possible to pass variable to WIX localization file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827931/is-it-possible-to-pass-variable-to-wix-localization-file/6833470#6833470) (for easy retrieval)
2. [Wix Installer : Setting component condition property when doing a MSIEXEC admin install at command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49449985/wix-installer-setting-component-condition-property-when-doing-a-msiexec-admin/49501700#49501700) (a lenghty description of preprocessor constructs versus other useful constructs to create flavors of setups)
3. [Wix toolset license agreement multi-languages issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49595758/wix-toolset-license-agreement-multi-languages-issue/49605354#49605354) (using localization)
4. [Wix string with characters not available in database 's codepage although codepage is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915225/wix-string-with-characters-not-available-in-database-s-codepage-although-codepa/15916923#15916923)
5. On various preprocessor constructs **`$(env.someval)`**, **`$(sys.someval)`**, **`$(var.someval)`**: https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html

Comment: additional info on variables (using localized strings containing other variables) would be useful.