# Installing SQL Server 2014 Express as a prerequisite in boostrapper

Tags: sql-server, wix, sql-server-express

I am trying to use boostrapper (Wix 3.11) to set up an installation, with SQL Server 2014 Express as a prerequisite.

It works well when I install `setup.exe` or `SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe` with command line.

The command line is the following :

```
SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe /q /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL 
       /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service"  
       /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" 
       /AGTSVCACCOUNT="NT AUTHORITY\Network Service" 
       /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /SECURITYMODE=SQL SAPWD="TestPassWord"
```

However, it fails when I try to run it from boostrapper. It always throws the same error.

> Error: Action "Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.SetupExtension.ValidateFeatureSettingsAction" threw an exception during execution.
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Setup.Chainer.Workflow.ActionExecutionException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: userName ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

The following is the code I'm using to set up an installer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"> 
      <?define Account = 'NT AUTHORITY\Network Service'?>
      <?define SAPassword = "TestPassWord"?>     
        <Bundle Name="Setup" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Company" UpgradeCode="{GUID}">
            <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
        <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
            LicenseUrl=""
            ThemeFile="HyperlinkTheme.xml"
            LocalizationFile="HyperlinkTheme.wxl"
            SuppressOptionsUI="yes" />
        </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
            <Chain>
          <ExePackage Id ="SQL_express" SourceFile="$(var.PreReqPath)\SQLExpress\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe" Compressed="yes" Vital="no" InstallCommand="/q /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSVCACCOUNT=$(var.Account) /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=$(var.Account) /AGTSVCACCOUNT=$(var.Account) /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=$(var.SAPassword)" />
            </Chain>
        </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

I have tried to add **Permachine="Yes"** to the ExePackage line but it doesn't solve the problem.

I have also tried to right-click on the installer and run it as administrator but it still doesn't work.

Hopefully someone can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't looked at this in a while, but nobody else seems to be around right now. I'll give it a go: I guess you are using **[pre-processor variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50444241/wix-windows-installer-xml-create-universal-variables/50452114#50452114)** in your source there, and not **runtime variables**. In other words the `"$(var.VariableName)"` entries are resolved at **build-time** (`when your WiX Bundle is compiled - which is sometimes OK`) and not at **run-time** (`when your WiX Bundle is installed - which is often desired`).

> In other words I would assume your **pre-processor variables** resolve to
>   blank strings during compilation, and that is why your install does
>   not work. There are no values specified at all for all pre-processor fields.
>
> As a test, maybe compile your bundle with some hard-coded values as a "[smoke test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_(software))", to determine if this is the case. Then try the [**`Variable element`**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/variable.html) described below.

***Mockup***:

```
<ExePackage Id ="SQL_express" SourceFile="SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe" Compressed="yes" Vital="no" InstallCommand="/q /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSVCACCOUNT=TestAccount /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=SqlAccount /AGTSVCACCOUNT=SvcAccount /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=SAPassword" />
```

---

Maybe you can have a look at **Neil Sleightholm's blog** for some ideas how to approach this (I don't have a fully working sample to add):
http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.com/2012/05/wix-burn-tipstricks.html

I think the key is the [**`Variable element`**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/variable.html):

```
<Variable Name="InstallFolder" Type="string" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]ACME\My App" />
```

It looks like you can override such values at the command line by setting the [**`Overridable attribute`**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/variable.html) to `yes` (bottom of the page for that link). I have never tried this. It looks like these Variable elements resolve using the standard MSI-brace convention: `[InstallFolder]`. Sample:

```
<MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
```

[**See Sleightholm's template again**](http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.com/2012/05/wix-burn-tipstricks.html) for full context for the above fragments. You will be using an [**`ExePackage`**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/exepackage.html) instead of an [**`MsiPackage`**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/msipackage.html) obviously.

It appears you can ignore the [**`WixVariable element`**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/wixvariable.html) for your use-case (as opposed to the [**`Variable element`**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/variable.html) which you will need).

Comment: After removing the pre-processor variables and giving the value directly, it works well. Thank you very much.